# AJAX PUT from jQuery to REST API not working - Error 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http, http-put

I am trying to update data using a PUT request which calls a .Net REST API. When I send the AJAX call it shows a 404 error.

```
  var url = "http://localhost/site/mycontrollerName/PUT"
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "PUT",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 
      "userId": userid ,
      "paramDate1":date1 ,
      "eventId1": _event1 ,
      "paramDate2": date2 ,
      "eventId2": _event2 
    },
    success: function (data) {
      // some task
    }
  , fail: function () {
    // some task
  }
})
```

```csharp
[HttpPut]
public JsonResult PUT(int userId, DateTime paramDate1, int eventId1, DateTime paramDate2, int eventId2)
{
  var response = "";
  return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

What is wrong here? I also tried to create an array for parameters and pass them as a JSON string. I also tried the below URLs, removing userid parameter:

```
http://localhost/site/mycontrollerName/1/PUT
```

and

```
http://localhost/site/mycontrollerName/PUT/1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193482/discussion-on-question-by-pavan-ajax-put-from-jquery-to-rest-api-not-working-e).

Answer (score 1):

This is IIS setting issue Open IIS->  handler Module -> search "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" -> Click on " request restriction" -> verbs   Then add PUT and DELETE in it.

Changed input data in ajax with Javascript object and stringyfy it before pass.

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Btw that was one of the config options in the article I gave you (on the comments now moved to chat), which you said you'd already implemented. The settings in your web.config should have overridden anything in IIS, so that's a bit odd

Comment: yes its really odd. IIS had override config settings. Now facing same problem for delete request but this time api is apicontroller not mvc

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a separate question about that one - since it's Web API the situation is potentially somewhat different.